# json.net custom jobject deserialization

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I'm trying to use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string) to deserialize a string into an jobject that can use with dynamic to access the json document on the fly. However I want to avoid knowing the casing of the document so I can type

```
dynamic document = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(someString);
Console.WriteLine(document.some.path.here.name);
```

and have it work on `{"Some":{"path":{"HERE":{"Name":"test"}}}`
I can't find out how to create a custom class for json.net that will do that for me, basically removing case sensitivity on the jobject (or maybe transform all properties to lower case)

Comment: You can try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247478/pascal-case-dynamic-properties-with-json-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To recursively convert all properties in a `JToken` hierarchy to lower case, you can use the following extension method:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static TJToken RenamePropertiesToLowerInvariant<TJToken>(this TJToken root) where TJToken : JToken
    {
        return root.RenameProperties(s => s.ToLowerInvariant());
    }

    public static TJToken RenameProperties<TJToken>(this TJToken root, Func<string, string> map) where TJToken : JToken
    {
        if (map == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (root == null)
            return null;
        if (root is JProperty)
        {
            return RenameReplaceProperty(root as JProperty, map, -1) as TJToken;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (IList<JToken> obj in root.DescendantsAndSelf().OfType<JObject>())
                for (int i = obj.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    RenameReplaceProperty((JProperty)obj[i], map, i);
            return root;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<JToken> DescendantsAndSelf(this JToken node)
    {
        if (node == null)
            return Enumerable.Empty<JToken>();
        var container = node as JContainer;
        if (container != null)
            return container.DescendantsAndSelf();
        else
            return new[] { node };
    }

    private static JProperty RenameReplaceProperty(JProperty property, Func<string, string> map, int index)
    {
        // JProperty.Name is read only so it will need to be replaced in its parent.
        if (property == null)
            return null;
        var newName = map(property.Name);
        if (newName == property.Name)
            return property;
        var value = property.Value;
        // Setting property.Value to null on the old property prevents the child JToken hierarchy from getting recursively cloned when added to the new JProperty
        // See https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/633#issuecomment-133358110
        property.Value = null; 
        var newProperty = new JProperty(newName, value);
        IList<JToken> container = property.Parent;
        if (container != null)
        {
            if (index < 0)
                index = container.IndexOf(property);
            container[index] = newProperty;
        }
        return newProperty;
    }
}
```

Then do

```
dynamic document = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(someString).RenamePropertiesToLowerInvariant();
```

However, [`JObject`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JObject.cs) is case sensitive and provides no constructor to use a case-invariant comparer in its [`JPropertyKeyedCollection`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JPropertyKeyedCollection.cs).  And [`JObjectDynamicProxy.TryGetMember()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JObject.cs#L807) seems to be doing a simple lookup not a case-insensitive search.

So, unless you can get [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42180717/3744182) to work, if you need a case-insensitive dynamic object, you could take one of the replacements for `ExpandoObject` from [How to set ExpandoObject's dictionary as case insensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760035/how-to-set-expandoobjects-dictionary-as-case-insensitive) then create your own version of [`ExpandoObjectConverter`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/ExpandoObjectConverter.cs) to deserialize your alternative expando type.

Comment: I'm afraid of the performance difference between jobject and my own expando object but seems to be the accepted route according to all the links provided in this q